# Spring ResponseEntity return PDF file, FileNotFoundException handling

Tags: java, spring, pdf

In a web project, the user needs to download a PDF file. I'm using Spring ResponseEntity to return a PDF file. Right now if the file is not found, I'm returning a

`new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);`

But in the front end the user get a blank page which is not so friendly. So what would be a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An ugly solution would be to change your return type to `Object`. In 200 cases, return a `ResponseEntity`. In 404 cases, return a `ModelAndView` and render a `jsp` with 404 messages.

Comment: I was think the same thing.

Comment: Another solution would be to send a redirect. Create your `ResponseEntity` with 302 and a `Location` header. It doesn't follow the HTTP spec to the word, but meh.